# Does C++ Algorithm/Boost Lib have Radix Sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I want to sort integers and I know radix sort is supposed to be awesome for it. Any library implementation for this sort?

Comment: There's a thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-devel-archive/KTN71zKHfPQ) which mentions that someone has written one, but it is awaiting review. I'm not aware of it having made it into boost yet, however.

Comment: @AyBayBay I think [Jeremy W. Murphy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/413597/jeremy-w-murphy) correctly answered the question. Could you accept his answer, or give me a reason why it's unacceptable?

Comment: @Yuushi Seems it [has been accepted in 1.58](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729170/85371)

Comment: Not in Boost or the standard library, but you might like [ska_sort](https://github.com/skarupke/ska_sort), which is a fine-tuned hybrid radix sort, with projections support: you can write `ska_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& value) { return value.foo; });` too sort on a specific `foo` field if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how strictly you define *radix sort*, since Boost 1.58.0 includes [Spreadsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsort), which is a hybrid sorting algorithm that heuristically mixes bucket and comparison sorting.

For sorting integers and with no requirement for worst-case Θ(n) efficiency, Spreadsort should satisfy you.

For argument's sake, you can also take a look at my implementation of [LSD radix sort](https://github.com/jeremy-murphy/algorithm/tree/speed_test), which is fairly inefficient with memory but occasionally faster than Spreadsort. You only require the radix_sort branch but I've linked to the speed_test branch because it has the readme.

Answer (score 2):

The more actual answer is **Yes** since 1.58 it does:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/sort/doc/html/index.html

It has something known as SpreadSort and will "magically" detect optimized paths for types like `std::string`, or floating point numbers that can be treated as byte arrays.

Comment: Does it optimize something like comparation in a struct operation<(T&const a, T&const b){return a.x<b.x}? If not is there any lib to do that?

Comment: @l4m2 it isn't automatic, but yes, you can convince it to do that.

Comment: @l4m2 I was out of my depth, but someone got to it already: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39400351#39400351 Big props to @ Morwenn the uncrowned king of cppsort

Comment: Here's the integer adaptation of the same http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/740fe1a67521d5cb @l4m2