# Algorithms for bucket sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How can I bucket sort an array of integers that contains negative numbers?
And, what's the difference between bucket sort and counting sort?

Comment: i don't know algorithm bucket sort with negative? I am sorry, i don't know more english, so help me.

Comment: Did you try an [internet search with the terms: bucket sort negative numbers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bucket%20sort%20negative%20numbers)?

Comment: Wikipedia explains the difference between [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) and [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) quite nicely.

Comment: @user3750552 StackOverflow can be very unforgiving, hang in there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/consideration-for-removing-the-downvote-button-from-questions/266670#266670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a link only answer but it gives you the information you need to formulate a good question.

[Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

Wikipedia's step 1, where you "Set up an array of initially empty buckets", will need to include buckets for negative numbers.

[Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

> "Compared to counting sort, bucket sort requires linked lists, dynamic arrays or a large amount of preallocated memory to hold the sets of items within each bucket, whereas counting sort instead stores a single number (the count of items) per bucket."

Comment: thank you. i try to use english, but i have a question: bucket sort or counting sort better?

Comment: @user3750552 That question is really outside the scope of StackOverflow to address. It will depend upon your individual needs. My personal preference is the algorithm that is already implemented: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21251061/2642059

Answer (score 6):

#### Bucket sort for negative values

Using Bucket sort for negative values simply requires mapping each element to a bucket proportional to its a distance from the minimal value to be sorted.

For example when using a bucket per value (as suggested above) for the following input would be as follows:

```
input array: {4, 2, -2, 2, 4, -1, 0}
min = -2
bucket0: {-2}
bucket1: {-1}
bucket2: {0}
bucket3: {}
bucket4: {2, 2}
bucket5: {}
bucket6: {4, 4}
```

#### Suggested algorithm

```
#A: array to be sorted
#count: number of items in A
#max: maximal value in A
#min: minimal value in A
procedure BucketSort(A, count, max, min)
    #calculate the range of item in each bucket
    bucketRange = (max - min + 1) / bucketsCount
    #distribute the item to the buckets
    for each item in A:
        bucket[(item.value - min) / bucketRange].push(item)
    #sort each bucket and build the sorted array A
    index = 0
    for bucket in {0...bucketsCount}:
        sort(bucket)
        for item in {0...itemsInBucket}:
            A[index] = item
            index++
```

#### C++ implementation

Notice the *bucketRange* which is proportional to the range between *max* and *min*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <stdlib.h>     // rand
#include <limits>       // numeric_limits

using namespace std;

#define MAX_BUCKETS_COUNT (10) // choose this according to your space limitations

void BucketSort(int * arr, int count, int max, int min)
{
    if (count == 0 or max == min)
    {
        return;
    }

    // set the number of buckets to use
    int bucketsCount = std::min(count, MAX_BUCKETS_COUNT);
    vector<int> *buckets = new vector<int>[bucketsCount];

    // using this range we will we distribute the items into the buckets
    double bucketRange = (((double)max - min + 1) / (bucketsCount));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        int bucket = (int)((arr[i] - min)  / bucketRange);
        buckets[bucket].push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bucketsCount; ++i)
    {
        // here we sort each bucket O(klog(k) - k being the number of item in the bucket
        sort(buckets[i].begin(), buckets[i].end());
        for (vector<int>::iterator iter = buckets[i].begin(); iter != buckets[i].end(); ++iter)
        {
            arr[index] = *iter;
            ++index;
        }
    }

    delete[] buckets;

}
```

#### Testing the code

```
int main ()
{
    int items = 50;
    int data[items];

    int shift = 15;//inorder to get some negative values in the array
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    printf("before sorting: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < items; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = rand() % items - shift;
        data[i] < min ? min = data[i]: true;
        data[i] > max ? max = data[i]: true;
        printf("%d ,", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    BucketSort(data, items, max, min);

    printf("after sorting: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < items; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ,", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking at your answer, I have a few comments. 1) You're not *really* answering the first question "*How can I bucket sort an array of integers that contains negative numbers?*". 2) The question hasn't mentioned any particular language - you've provided a C++ implementation without much explanation or comments which a non-C++ developer may find difficult to digest. 3) You've not answered the second question "*what's the difference between bucket sort and counting sort?*"

Answer (score 1):

**Bucket sort, or bin sort**, is a sorting algorithm that works by distributing the elements of an array into a number of buckets. Each bucket is then sorted individually, either using a different sorting algorithm, or by recursively applying the bucket sorting algorithm.

Steps:

1. Set up an array of initially empty "buckets".
2. **Scatter**: Go over the original array, putting each object in its bucket.
3. Sort each non-empty bucket.
4. **Gather**: Visit the buckets in order and put all elements back into the original array.

Bucket sort assumes that the input is drawn from a uniform distribution and has an average-case running time of O(n). The computational complexity estimates involve the number of buckets.

**Worst case performance: O(n^2)**

**Best case performance: Omega(n+k)**

**Average case performance: Theta(n+k)**

**Worst case space complexity: O(n.k)**

**For implementation and pictographic understanding:**

http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2015/11/bucket-sort-or-bin-sort.html

Answer (score -1):

Bucket Sort needs an ordered dictionary with the unique values as the keys with their respective frequencies as the values. This is what the first line does and assigns this dictionary to k.

The second line returns a python list using double list comprehension to output the ordered key 'frequency' times. Sum(..., []) flattens

```
neglist = [-1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 8, -2, 7, 8, 0, -3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 15, 12, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 15]
poslist = [4, 2, 7, 9, 12, 3, 7]


def bucket(k):
    k = dict((uni, k.count(uni)) for uni in list(set(k)))
    return sum(([key for i in range(k.get(key))] for key in sorted(k.keys())), [])


print("NegList: ", bucket(neglist))
print("PosList: ", bucket(poslist))

'''
NegList:  [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 12, 15, 15]
PosList:  [2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 9, 12]
'''
```

Comment: Could you add some explination? Code-only answers might solve the immediate problem, but they aren't very helpful to future users.  What problem exactly does this solve, and how?