# Apply multiple Ranges to one list

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a long list of data which needs to be sorted by range, and then I need to count the integers in each range. The following code works if you continually input the range i.e. 0-101, 100-201, 200-301, etc. 
Is there a way to write this code so that I do not have to input each range?

```
import collections 
first_range = [ ] 
f = open("numbers.txt")
count1 = collections.Counter()
for line in f:
    for number in line.split():
        count1.update((number,))
        if number > '0' and number < '101':
            first_range.append(number)
print(len(first_range))
```

example data from number.txt:
[209, 166, 38]

Expected output:
0-101 = x
100-201 = y 
etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data in `numbers.txt` and expected output?

Comment: @Wondercricket Done : )

Comment: Are all the ranges of fixed length like your examples? And are they inclusive of the first number in the range and exclusive of the last, also like your examples?

Comment: @jack6e Yes, they are exactly like the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain an upper bound, iterate in sorted list, when number exceeds bound increase bound by 100

```
import random
lisst = [209, 166, 38, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1099, 2011]
cnts = []
cnt = 0
up = 100
for num in sorted(lisst):
    if num <= up:
        cnt+=1
    else:
        while num > up:
            cnts.append(cnt)
            cnt=0
            up+=100
        cnt=1
cnts.append(cnt)
for i in range(len(cnts)):
    print(str(i*100+1) + "-" + str(i*100+100) + " = " + str(cnts[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but do you know how to edit the above code to include 0 so the ranges are 0, 1-100, 101-200, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer division to break the numbers into ranges, and then use the values from the integer division to put the values into a list, so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nums = [10, 50, 210, 300, ...]
bin_sort = defaultdict([])

for num in nums:
    bin_sort[num//100].append(num)
```

bin_sort will contain all the values that you need organized into what range increment you are on. So to get the 0-100 bin you would print:

```
>>>print(bin_sort[1])
[10, 50, ...]
```

It's also worth looking at bucket sorts for this sort of thing ([Algorithms for bucket sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254306/algorithms-for-bucket-sort))

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible iterative solution:

```
import math

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers = [int(x) for x in f.readlines()]
    ranges = math.ceil(max(numbers) / 100)

    for r in range(ranges):
        bottom = r * 100
        top = bottom + 101
        range_count = [num for num in numbers if num in range(bottom, top)]
        print('Number in Range {}: {}'.format(r, len(range_count)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you and doesn't require external libraries like `collections`

```
ranges = { # (start, end): [count, [number list]]
(0, 101): [0, []],
(101, 201): [0, []],
(201, 301): [0, []]
}

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        numbers = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
        for num in numbers:
            for start, end in ranges.keys():
                if start <= num < end:
                    ranges[(start, end)][0] += 1
                    ranges[(start, end)][1].append(num)

for range_ in ranges.keys():
    print("{}-{}: {}".format(range_[0], range_[1], ranges[range_][0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!