# Finding Average across multiple ranges

Tags: python

I am trying to find the average of numbers in list in certain ranges. The following code was an answer to a similar question ([Apply multiple Ranges to one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378377/apply-multiple-ranges-to-one-list))

```
import random
lisst = [209, 166, 38, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1099, 2011]
cnts = []
cnt = 0
up = 100
for num in sorted(lisst):
    if num <= up:
        cnt+=1
    else:
        while num > up:
            cnts.append(cnt)
            cnt=0
            up+=100
        cnt=1
cnts.append(cnt)
for i in range(len(cnts)):
    print(str(i*100+1) + "-" + str(i*100+100) + " = " + str(cnts[i]))
```

I have tried to edit in something like this:

```
for integers in zip(range(0, 10**10, 10**7), range(10**7 +1, 10**10, 
10**7)):
    ave = sum(integers)/len(integers)
```

This code works to count the numbers in ranges, but is there any way to alter this so that it find the average of all the numbers in range for each range? Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried? it seems that you put no effort to attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach to calculation of this kind is called *binning*. First you 'bin' the items in the list by size (or whatever criterion is involved) and then you calculate the statistics of interest. I use equal size bins in this code for simplicity.

`bins` is a dictionary. The key for each item is the upper value for the bin, and dictionary values are the counts and sums for the bin. As we go through the list we accumulate counts and sums in the bins.

Since the sizes of the bins are equal we can use a little computational trick to convert the values in `lisst` into bin numbers: `((num - 1)//500)*500+500`, `//` being integer division. (Just try it out if you're unfamiliar with it.)

After going through `lisst` we print out the bins in order, calculating averages as we go.

```
>>> lisst = [209, 166, 38, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1099, 2011]
>>> bins = { _: {'count': 0, 'sum':0} for _ in [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]}
>>> for num in lisst:
...     bins[((num - 1)//500)*500+500]['count'] += 1
...     bins[((num - 1)//500)*500+500]['sum'] += num
...     
>>> for bin in [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]:
...     bin, 'sum', bins[bin]['sum'], 'count', bins[bin]['count'], 'average', bins[bin]['sum'] / bins[bin]['count'] if bins[bin]['count'] else None
...     
(500, 'sum', 413, 'count', 3, 'average', 137.66666666666666)
(1000, 'sum', 0, 'count', 0, 'average', None)
(1500, 'sum', 4372, 'count', 4, 'average', 1093.0)
(2000, 'sum', 0, 'count', 0, 'average', None)
(2500, 'sum', 2011, 'count', 1, 'average', 2011.0)
```

Edit: Code in standard form.

```
lisst = [209, 166, 38, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1099, 2011]
bins = { _: {'count': 0, 'sum':0} for _ in [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]}
for num in lisst:
    bins[((num - 1)//500)*500+500]['count'] += 1
    bins[((num - 1)//500)*500+500]['sum'] += num

for bin in [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]:
    print (bin, 'sum', bins[bin]['sum'], 'count', bins[bin]['count'], 'average', bins[bin]['sum'] / bins[bin]['count'] if bins[bin]['count'] else None)
```

**Edit in response to most recent comment:**

```
lisst = [917529326, 1468789076, 1678667190, 647403601, 1713311112, 0]

bin_size = 10**7

bins_list = range(63*10**7,172*10**7+bin_size, bin_size)
bins = { _: {'count': 0, 'sum':0} for _ in bins_list}

outliers = []
for num in lisst:
    bin_number = ((num - 1)//bin_size)*bin_size+bin_size
    if not bin_number in bins:
        outliers.append(num)
        continue
    bins[bin_number]['count'] += 1
    bins[bin_number]['sum'] += num

print ('outlier values:', outliers)

for bin in bins:
    if bins[bin]['count']:
        print (bin, 'sum', bins[bin]['sum'], 'count', bins[bin]['count'], 'average', bins[bin]['sum'] / bins[bin]['count'] if bins[bin]['count'] else None)
```

Output:

```
outlier values: [0]
650000000 sum 647403601 count 1 average 647403601.0
1720000000 sum 1713311112 count 1 average 1713311112.0
1470000000 sum 1468789076 count 1 average 1468789076.0
1680000000 sum 1678667190 count 1 average 1678667190.0
920000000 sum 917529326 count 1 average 917529326.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Unfortunately, when I run your exact code, I get an output that eventually gets to the correct answer but prints a different output 8 times since there are 8 numbers in the list. The first section of output is the following -Any advice?
500 sum 209 count 1 average 209.0
1000 sum 0 count 0 average None
1500 sum 0 count 0 average None
2000 sum 0 count 0 average None
2500 sum 0 count 0 average None

Comment: You're very welcome. I ran the code again and it gave the same results as I had before. You might have had a problem transcribing the code. I've edited my answer with a version of the code that should be easier to copy. I hope that does it for you.

Comment: Got it! Thank you : )

Comment: I hate to bug you again, but I need to apply this code to a different data set that is a long string in a text file, when I try to use the code you posted with the addition of: for line in filename: for num in line.split(","): then the code. When I run this I get an error with reads: KeyError:0. Can oyu offer any advice on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Try: `import re; lisst = [int(_) for _ in re.split(r'\s+', open('temp.txt').read()) if _]`

Comment: I get the following error                                                                  
                                                                                                       
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,'

Comment: Replace the `int` with `float`.

Comment: Hmmm it still isn't working- now I get this error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,'       I will keep looking into it though because I think it has to do with the comma

Comment: It appears that there are commas between the numbers as well as blanks. Google for help with that. You're almost certain to find a StackOverflow question that considers it.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: It's been my pleasure.

Comment: I think I am getting the error because there is a 0 in my data set-interesting

Comment: 917529326 1468789076 1678667190 647403601 1713311112 0

Comment: See this I've only now just taken another glimpse at the final part of your question. What would the bins be into which you want to group your data?

Comment: For this new data set- by the 10,000,000's so 10000000, 20000000, 30000000 etc.

Comment: So it's the same as before?

Comment: No, different. I must have forgot to press save edit!